# Python script not finding value in log file when the value is in the file

Tags: python, logging

The code below is meant to find any xls or csv file used in a process. The .log file contains full paths with extensions and definitely contains multiple values with "xls" or "csv". However, Python can't find anything...Any idea? The weird thing is when I copy the content of the log file and paste it to another notepad file and save it as log, it works then...

```
infile=r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.log"
important=[]
keep_words=["xls","csv"]

with open(infile,'r') as f:
    for line in f:  
        for word in keep_words:
            if word in line:
                important.append(line)

print(important)
```

Comment: What's in the log file?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a line in `test.log` that doesn't get found, but should have been?

Comment: 4/16/2020 10:10:26 AM: 0150  [..\ExternalData\Dispensing U.S. Sales Summary\OS Migration Contracts.xlsx]

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your result with the log line you posted. Your code is working for me.

Comment: @DavidDenni Even with the complete log file you posted in the answer comments section, your code works. Are there any other details that may be missing? Perhaps this is not the complete code? Can you add some debug logs in the code and run it? Print the `line` maybe

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out...encoding issue...

```
with io.open(infile,encoding='utf16') as f:
```

Answer (score -1):

You must change the line

```
for line in f:
```

to

```
for line in f.readlines():
```

You made the python search in the bytes opened file, not in his content, even in his lines (in a list, just like the readlines method);

I hope I was able to help (sorry about my bad English).

Comment: The file is opened in `r` mode - which is a text mode. And `for line in f` iterates over the lines in the file - not the "bytes".

Comment: But to read the lines as a iterable you need to use this method, however it will iterate the file openned representation. Don't matter in which mode the file is open, you must use the f as a open(file, mode), because is what he is.

Comment: No. For a file opened in text mode the iterator for `f` would be over the lines in the file. Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Man, i literally tried that and returned me the following error: ``` UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: You should check if your test file is actually a text file or not. The file in the question is a text file. The code you have posted in your answer will work - because it's the same as OPs code, just less efficient. And OPs code is already working for me.

Comment: I tried and no success, still not returning anything...The file is .log by the way.

Comment: However, i'm just telling to try that way, but if isn't what it can be? We don't know the exception the python is raising even it message.

Comment: @DavidDenni may you just show us the error message that it's returning. To help us to understand it?

Comment: when "printing" my dataframe, it is empty, showing [] instead of returning the lines that contain "xls" or "csv"

Comment: @DavidDenni Are you sure about the .log file content? If you are loading from another .log file, are you sure about the log file you're reading?

Comment: @GiullianoRossi I provided a link to the file, to download.

Comment: Thanks, i will test a solution and post another answer.

Comment: @DavidDenni Are you sure about the file encoding, i tried to open it using the UTF-8 encoding and didn't worked, the python couldn't even read it using the default encoding

Comment: @GiullianoRossi I'm able to read the file. If, in my code, you replace in line by not in line, then you will see all of the lines being printed...

Comment: Hey i tried to load every line with the python and the result is \x004\x00/\x001\x006\x00/\x002\x000\x002\x000\x00 \x001\x000\x00:\x002\x001\x00:\x004\x002\x00 \x00A\x00M\x00:\x00 \x002\x000\x008\x005\x00 . What apparently happens is a problem with the charset, because the python isn't understanding the content, so he can't search for anything in the line